# What is the proper way of storing data into scope after the service retrieves data from a URL?

Tags: angularjs

I have an FirstController that is loaded on page load. When a user clicks a button on it, it triggers an ng-switch that loads up a SecondController that is responsible for managing the content of 3 graphs that use data from $scope.data1, $scope.data2, $scope.data3. When SecondController loads, it initializes a service that retrieves data. My problem is in my current setup.

```
myApp.controller('SecondController', ['DataService', function(DataService) {

    DataService.getMyData(); // this starts a call to a service method that contains an $http call that gets the data. I don't want the DataService to be getting the data until SecondController is loaded.

    $scope.myData1 = DataService.getAgeData(); // This fails now because the getMyData() call within the service has not completed when this is called.

    $scope.myData2 = DataService.getNameData(); // This fails now because the getMyData() call within the service has not completed when this is called.

    $scope.myData3 = DataService.getCountyData(); // This fails now because the getMyData() call within the service has not completed when this is called.
}]);
```

Within an HTML template, I have the following 3 times:

```
<chartdata data="myData1"></chartdata>
```

What is the proper way to do this? Code examples would be helpful.

NOTE: getMyData() shoves the data in a "this.asyncData" variable. The methods "getAgeData, getNameData, and getCountyData" all do filtering/transformation on this.asyncData", so there is no $http in those functions.

Comment: callbacks, promises, and/or by reference.

Comment: Can you show me a sample of what the ideal way to do this is? That is hopefully not dreadfully unorganized and complicated? I am looking for best practice of today, not options. Samples I see that are not best practice shove the $http call in the controller http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/requesting-json-data-with-ajax.html, which I don't think is the right way to go. Promises are not clear, I use promises from within the service, but have no idea how to bring it back to the controller if possible.

Comment: Downvoter should have given a reason.  The problem you're having is that getMyData seems to be async, so you should wait until the promise completes in order to to access the data from it.

Comment: I think he knows what the problem is, seeing the comments in the code snippet.

Comment: I downvoted because there is no way to answer this question without building a service from scratch. It would also help to show your attempts at solving this so we would have something to start with. If you're asking which technique would be best, that's off topic for stackoverflow and should be closed.

Comment: He's probably doing an $http call in the service and not giving a 'return' on the promise.  I agree the service implementation would've been helpful, but you can say that instead of just downvoting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `DataService.getMyData()` has an $http call in it, then it's async, and it won't necessarily complete by the time you call `DataService.getAgeData()`.

If you **return** the **promise** from the $http call, you can then do your next three methods after `getMyData()` is completed.

```
function getMyData() {
    return this.$http
        .get('....')
        .then(function (response) {
            //note that this return is an optional link in the promise chain,
            //and it could just be a void operation here
            return response.data;
        });
}
```

I just took a second look at your controller and if I were you I would actually change it to set all 3 as async operations:

```
myApp.controller('SecondController', SecondController);

SecondController.$inject = ['DataService'];
function SecondController(DataService) {
    DataService.getAgeData().then(function (ageData) { $scope.myData1 = ageData; });
    DataService.getNameData().then(function (nameData) { $scope.myData2 = nameData; });
    DataService.getCountyData().then(function (countyData) { $scope.myData3 = countyData; });
}
```

Be sure to also check out John Papa's style guide, for best practices, when you get a chance -- especially the "controllerAs" syntax:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide

**Update based on your comments:**

```
function getMyData() {
    return this.$http
        .get('....')
        .then(function (response) {
            //note that this return is an optional link in the promise chain,
            //and it could just be a void operation here
            this.cachedData = response.data;
        });
}
```

-

```
myApp.controller('SecondController', SecondController);
SecondController.$inject = ['DataService'];
function SecondController(DataService) {
    DataService.getMyData().then(function () {
        $scope.ageData = DataService.getAgeData();
        $scope.nameData = DataService.getNameData();
        $scope.countyData = DataService.getCountyData();
    });
}
```

Comment: The DataService.getMyData() is the only method in the service that has an $http call in it.  getAgeData and getNameData are all getting their data from the "this.asyncdata" variable (with filtering and transformation) so that there is no need to make an $http request every time getAgeData, getNameData, etc is called.

Comment: In that case you can replace _return response.data;_ with _service.asyncData = response.data;_.

The controller call becomes DataService.getMyData().then(function() { ... do the three assignments... });

Comment: Wait, but if all three are calling DataService.getMyData() is this going to make it such that the http call is made 3 times? One for each "getAgeData, getNameData, and getCountyData()?

Comment: If the only $http call is in the getMyData, then it'll finish that call and then move on to the assignments.  Think of it like an english sentence: getMyData().then(do this { $scope.myData1 = DataService.getAgeData(); $scope.myData2 = DataService.getNameData(); $scope.myData3 = DataService.getCountyData(); });

Comment: Instead of wrapping the contents of SecondController with the service call, is there some way to make it such that it returns the "this.cachedData" of the service or the $http call if it has not been made yet?